# How to remove SVN history from java files?

Tags: regex, svn, ant

I have various projects that had files with SVN history in them. I recently moved those projects to a Mercurial repository so now that history within the file is useless. Is there a way to remove those which is not by hand?

Here's an example:

```
/*
 * $Rev:x$
 * $LastChangedDate:x$
 * $LastChangedBy:x$
 */
```

Where x is a value in the files. I assume some sort of regex would help. Any idea?

Edit:

This is the working answer:

```
<target name="remove-svn-history">
    <replaceregexp byline="false" match="\A/\*.*?\*/" replace="">
        <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that's at the beginning of the file, you could match it with the following regex:

```
\A/\*.*?\*/
```

Comment: I tried it but had no luck. I'll update the question with the ant task I have so far.

Comment: It occurs to me that I was using the assumption that dot matches newline. Not familiar with ant/java regex enough to know whether that's enabled by default or not. Try adding (?s) to the beginning, i.e. (?s)\\A/\\*.*?\\*/

Comment: Just noticed you've got byline="true", which apparently forces it to process line by line. The regex I wrote is meant to capture the whole comment block. Try setting byline to false, which is the default according to http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html .